# Drupal file upload field via popup

Tags: forms, ajax, files, javascript

So I'm using a "file" type input inside a form which is called within a popup...but then whenever I submit that form inside the popup after having selected a file, the popup always return an error....

Is there a way to prevent this from happening and to successfully submit the form accordingly even with a file upload?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: it's a custom error message...it calls the Popups.errorMessage function in popups.js pretty much

Comment: Some more detail is needed to actually answer this question. Please explain in great detail what's going on and maybe post some code snippets as well to illustrate.

Answer (score -1):

I made it by creating 'VIEWS' by selecting the facebook style micro publisher images as 'field' and filtered according to my requirement.